# How to fully remove all packages installed by 'gnome-session-fallback'?

Tags: unity, gnome, uninstall, gnome-classic, software-uninstall

I mainly use Unity, but I installed gnome with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

To test how it was, but then I managed to delete all of my settings for my startup applications, so basically Gnome does not load properly now. And what I really need to do is to reinstall Gnome, but when I try just first of all uninstalling it with:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-session-fallback
```

This does not remove all of those 50-100 extra Gnome packages which it installed when I first installed it. So that is really my question, how do I fully remove Gnome and all of the extra packages installed by `gnome-session-fallback`, so that I can reinstall?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

```
gnome-session-fallback:
  Installed: 1:3.8.1-2ubuntu4
  Candidate: 1:3.8.1-2ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.8.1-2ubuntu4 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove `gnome-session-flashback` or `gnome-session-fallback`:

1. `sudo apt-get purge gnome-session-fallback`
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove # Uninstall unneeded Packages`
3. `sudo apt-get autoclean  # Delete packages no longer installed`

You could just ask apt to re-install it for you however:

1. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session-fallback`

If you're still having trouble (and aren't in any rush):

1. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: I tried that, but it did not uninstall any other packages other than `gnome-session-fallback`. And I remember an awful lot of other packages being installed as well when I installed that.

Comment: What does `ubuntu-desktop` reinstall? Is that everything? And would there be any danger in doing that?

Comment: There is always 'danger' when installing/removing/re-installing packages.  `ubuntu-desktop` is a group of packages that is very *core* to Ubuntu, but in this case, it would help re-install your gnome packages.