# gnome-session-flashback.target is a disabled or a static unit

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management

On Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)

Hello,
I uninstalled my amdgpu driver along with my video card and it bricked my GNOME session - I get an endless login loop.
My unity session works fine. If I try to reinstall the classic session, I get:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-session-flashback

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-91 linux-headers-4.15.0-91-generic linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-91-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-91-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 5140 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 gnome-session-flashback all 1:3.28.0-1ubuntu1.4 [5140 B]
Fetched 5140 B in 0s (107 kB/s)                   
(Reading database ... 303131 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-session-flashback_1%3a3.28.0-1ubuntu1.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-session-flashback (1:3.28.0-1ubuntu1.4) over (1:3.28.0-1ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up gnome-session-flashback (1:3.28.0-1ubuntu1.4) ...
gnome-session-flashback.target is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
```

I've installed the card again, with the exact same amdgpu-pro driver, but this error continues to persist.

Any help is appreciated!

Regards,
L. B.

Comment: You will need to check log files to see if there are any errors related to gnome-flashback.

Comment: In /var/log/syslog I see the following /that I believe is related to the flashback session/: "Could not get session id for session. Check that logind is properly installed and pam_systemd is getting used at login."

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-session-fallback
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session-flashback
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Note: the penultimate command will fail again, but ignore this. I suspect that only the last command is really needed, but this is what I did as a sequence exactly.

I followed this post:
[How to fully remove all packages installed by 'gnome-session-fallback'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599302/how-to-fully-remove-all-packages-installed-by-gnome-session-fallback)

Regards,
L. B.